# str_word_count() that works with Eastern languages in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

What would be a correct approach to creating a function that counts words in more languages than `str_word_count()`? Specifically, I need to support Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.

I'm think it would be something like this:

1. Somehow check if less than 50% of the characters are multibyte. If true, use `str_word_count()` and return.
2. Remove all continuous alphanumeric characters and add 1 to the count for each (assume these are Western words).
3. Remove all spaces and punctuation. Add string length to count.
4. Return count.

Are there better approaches? I can think of some flaws off the top of my head: accented characters, multibyte languages that use spaces to delimit words (e.g. Arabic, I believe).

Comment: Probably related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290537/is-php-str-word-count-multibyte-safe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084623/creating-an-effective-word-counter-including-chinese-japanese-and-other-accented

Comment: To count words, you need to know what a word is. `str_word_count` works on the assumption that words a delimited by some space character – which is not the case for many Asian languages. Your algorithm outline looks fine, but I would bet that there are existing solutions out there.

Comment: @feeela I couldn't find any existing solutions, and neither of those questions are of much help.

Answer (score 3):

[What about using ICU?](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis#TOC-Count-the-words-in-a-document-C-only-%3a) Which is interfaced in PHP by intl extension (class [IntlBreakIterator](http://php.net/IntlBreakIterator)).

Something like this:

```
function utf8_word_count($string, $mode = 0) {
    static $it = NULL;

    if (is_null($it)) {
        $it = IntlBreakIterator::createWordInstance(ini_get('intl.default_locale'));
    }

    $l = 0;
    $it->setText($string);
    $ret = $mode == 0 ? 0 : array();
    if (IntlBreakIterator::DONE != ($u = $it->first())) {
        do {
            if (IntlBreakIterator::WORD_NONE != $it->getRuleStatus()) {
                $mode == 0 ? ++$ret : $ret[] = substr($string, $l, $u - $l);
            }
            $l = $u;
        } while (IntlBreakIterator::DONE != ($u = $it->next()));
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

(implies intl extension enabled and PHP >= 5.5.0)

Comment: I've been using this with pretty good results. A few notes that others may find interesting.

(1) Getting this to work with Chinese I found I had to upgrade Intl and ICU (I didn't experiment to find min versions)

(2) Passing the locale argument seems to make no difference. Script can be mixed it seems. (would like to be proven wrong)

(3) I found the simpler `foreach` iteration was faster than the example above.